# How to exlude tests from included dependecies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

We have a gradle file where the upper webservices is dependent of the lower project core.

In the build.gradle of webservices the dependecy is included:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':core')
}
```

But now things are going strange. When I run a test inside IntelliJ the whole test of core will start until finally the single test case of webservices will start.
Even on the command line I run into the same problem:

```
/opt/gradle/gradle-7.5.1/bin/gradle webservices:test --tests com.example.MyTests.test
```

end in the funny behaviour that the complete core test are running:

```
> Configure project :core
> Task :core:test
```

In the test section of webservices is nothing else as:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Trying to exclude the tests of core by adding something like

```
exclude '**/core/**'
```

are not ending in the behaviour I would expect.

It there a way to tell gradle not include the tests of the project which is inside the depedency?

EDIT: Add some information after User51 comment:
/opt/gradle/gradle-7.5.1/bin/gradle web:test --dry-run

```
> Configure project :core
BUILD NUMBER: -1
BUILD DATE: 2023-02-02_08-58-47
clean synchronize dir
spi.Extension touched!...
:abc:compileJava SKIPPED
[...]
:abc:test SKIPPED
:abc:jar SKIPPED
:core:compileJava SKIPPED
[...]
:core:test SKIPPED
:core:updateTestTimestamps SKIPPED
:core:jar SKIPPED
:webservices:wsdl2javaTask SKIPPED
:webservices:compileJava SKIPPED
[...]
:webservices:test SKIPPED
```

Futher in the build.gradle of core is written this:

```
if (project.hasProperty("RUN_TESTS_FOR_JAR") && RUN_TESTS_FOR_JAR.equals("false")) {
    println "Tests are skipped!..."
    jar.dependsOn(updateTestTimestamps)
} else {
    jar.dependsOn(test, updateTestTimestamps)
}
build.dependsOn(updateTestTimestamps)
```

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: Gradle shouldn't run the tests of another module unless explicitly told to.  Trying things like `./gradlew clean webs:test --dry-run` would list the tasks to be run, in order.  That might give you some idea of why?  Also, a `./gradlew clean webs:ass` to see if they're being included as part the build task, or as part of the webs:test task.  Without seeing your actual `build.gradle`, unless there's a `.dependsOn` or a `.finalizedBy` directly including your core tests, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: @User51 I think you answered my question. I assume that the *depends on* in the core project seems the issue.